# BSOD from atikmpag.sys at boot

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

I have a HP ENVY 17 (17t-3200), Win 7 x64 that BSODs at boot.  The video driver for my Radeon HD 7850M is at fault.

The usual pattern is:

- Boot and login.
- Wait ~30 seconds.
- BSOD.
- Reboot and repeat 1-3 times.
- If it doesn't crash in the first minute, the computer runs fine indefinitely, even through sleep and resume.

The driver is the one [HP has available](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5275345#N349), 8.951.9.1000, which hasn't been updated since my model was released.  I've had this problem since getting the machine, and RMA'd the first one.  The second one has the same problem.

Because this machine has switchable graphics (with a Intel HD 4000), I can't install the [generic drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx#1) from AMD.

What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The fact it fails within the first 30 seconds suggests it could be a windows service or a scheduled task which fires when your PC gets into Windows. Can you check and remove all thing which are not required? Try to disable Aero as well (if using)

Comment: @DaveRook: This happens on a fresh Windows install.

Comment: About a year ago I had similar problems after I both updated my graphics drivers and ran windows updates. Booting in safe mode (and thus falling back to the generic graphics drivers at 800x600) allowed me to check the event logs. In my case it turned out to be a conflict between windows defender and the ATI drivers. Whatever it is in your case (same or something else) you might just enough enough information in the event logs to solve it.